# django migration error (django_content_type)

Tags: django, migration

I am trying to do a --fake-initial migration in django (1.9.7), but it gives me a strange error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")
```

as far as I know 'name' is not a column in 1.9.7 content_type anymore.

Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you do any upgrading from prior 1.8?

Comment: I didnt use django prior 1.8 during development of this app at all.

Comment: I just tried to add a name column to the django_content table manually and the migration worked. Django even removed the column during migration.

Answer (score 5):

The last comment seems to be an "answer."  I, too, encountered this – and no, Django other than 2.0 had never been here.  However, adding the column to the table (Varchar(100)) silenced the error.  Then, migrate *did* remove the column.  Go figure.  But, that's an "answer."

Comment: The same problem happened to me right now, out of the blue. And the same solution worked for me.